# asp.net c# google api Documents - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code

```
DocumentsService vService = new DocumentsService("test");
vService.setUserCredentials("vUserName", "vPassword");
RequestSettings vSettings = new RequestSettings("test");
DocumentsRequest vDocReq = new DocumentsRequest(vSettings);
Feed<Document> vFeed = vDocReq.GetEverything();
foreach (Document d in vFeed.Entries) {
  lbxDocumente.Items.Add(d.Title + " " + d.Author);
}
```

Why do I get this exception?

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is trying to authenticate with the *actual* strings "vUserName" and "vPassword":

```
vService.setUserCredentials("vUserName", "vPassword");
```

Did you mean it to be this instead, in order to use variables which you've initialized elsewhere?

```
vService.setUserCredentials(vUserName, vPassword);
```

(What's with the `v` prefix, by the way? I generally don't like prefixes like this at all, but I've never even *seen* `v` as a prefix before...)

EDIT: You're also not associating the request with the service anywhere. I've tried this code, and it works fine:

```
DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("test");
service.setUserCredentials(user, password);
RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("test");
DocumentsRequest docReq = new DocumentsRequest(settings);
docReq.Service = service;
Feed<Document> feed = docReq.GetEverything();
foreach (Document d in feed.Entries) {
  Console.WriteLine(d.Title);
}
```

Comment: same thing because the "vUserName" is the username and "vPassword" is the password , and the v prefix is for the variable

Comment: @xnl96: It's not the same thing; `"vUserName"` is a string literal; `vUserName` is a variable. They're very different things. I would strongly advise against the prefix, as it's just adding clutter with no benefit. Anyway, I believe your biggest problem was failing to associate the service with the request - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the problem "docReq.Service = service;
"